# Is there a comment style for starting a section in the code?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, coding-style

I'm referring to cases where I have different functionality in the class that it wouldn't make sense to break down to smaller classes.

For example, in Python, I personally like to use

```py
class DataStream:

  ################################
  # Read stream functionality
  ################################

  def read():
    pass

  def decode():
    pass

  ################################
  # Parse stream functionality
  ################################

  def exract_data():
    pass

  def map_data_types():
    pass

  ################################
  # Analyze functionality
  ################################

  def aggregated_data():
    pass

  def deduce_insights():
    pass
```

AFAIK, there is no convention for such comments.

Is there a convention for this in Java?
Or any format that Intellij can make something useful out of it?
For example, it would be great if Intellij would be able to collapse these sections.

Comment: Most folks in Java use the Java doc standard, and also look at the documentation for the standard API for style hints.

Comment: There isn't anything in Oracle's manual on section headers. That is why I'm asking.

Comment: AFAIK there is no such thing in [Oracle Java conventions](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/codeconventions-comments.html). So do as you want, or as your organization wants.

Comment: It's not an issue of what my organization wants, but I'm more concerned about what others find readable or is a common practice.

Comment: There's no common practice about this case and "finding it readable" is subjective (that's why conventions are made). So here I agree with you it be easier/interesting is there was one, but there isn't. So either do as you think as the most readable, or do as your organization/co-worker/clients/? think as more readble

Comment: Some IDE code formatters can be configured to group and sort members in a specific order which can achieve this implicitly without the need for a header. (all private properties, all public methods, all getters/setters etc) If you use a formatter configured like this it seems redundant to need a header as well

Comment: How will the IDE know that a set of method share common functionality?

Comment: Additionally, if you are using language features like scope to indicate public apis vs private/internal methods there's no reason why you should need to document a private method as an internal method because by language convention I already know it is internal if it's private

Comment: Re. sharing common functionality, that should be done by your design and how you structure your code, not enforced by documentation. e.g. Structure your code so like is with like and don't rely on documentation for this purpose

Comment: @KevinHooke I'm not sure what you mean by design for this purpose. I updated the question to reflect better the type of "section" I'm referring to.

Comment: The only time that something applies to other items below it, no matter how long the list of items below it becomes, is a line in a block of code.  Comments don't work that way, and you're trying to foist a paradigm that doesn't work for comments, which only apply to the things immediately below (or on the same line) as the comment.  There is no best practice to do something that's a bad practice, so that's why you won't get a satisfactory answer.

Comment: I'm closing the question for the lack of fruitful discussion

Answer (score 0):

Instead of relying on grouping related functional methods in close proximity in the source code and indicating the relationship with code comments, you should design and implement your code in way that takes advantage of features of the language and makes the purpose explicit.

For example, instead of grouping cooking methods and baking methods in the same class, you could implement this using different classes:

```
public class BakingOven{

    public Result bakeBread(){
    }

    public Result bakeCake(){
    }
}


public class FryingPan{

    public Result fryChicken(){
    }
    
    public Result frySteak(){
    }
}
```

This could be taken further by passing what it is to be baked or fried as a parameter, or you could indentify commmon interfaces like Fry, or Bake and have the classes implement those interfaces.

This is more of a design and how to structure your code more clearly type of problem than thinking about it as a documentation type problem.

Comment: Thanks. I see you got good intentions here. But I'm sure that over-engineering the code is not the right solution here.

Comment: @LiranFunaro This doesn't look like overengineering to me, but I would remove the "Baking" from "BakingOven".  Remember that engineering code isn't done to say "let's force everyone to do it my way" it's engineered to overcome a problem, like the one you presented.  If there is no problem to overcome, then doing engineering is overengineering, even if it is a simple design.

Comment: I see your point. I guess the problem is with the example I gave. I'll try to come up with a better one.

Comment: @EdwinBuck I update the class. I hope it makes more sense now.

Comment: With your updated example the same suggestions apply if you structure your code grouping related functionality, e.g. using a DataStreamReader and a DataStreamParser

Comment: The core Java libraries are full of examples like this. Look at implementations for the BufferedReader/BufferedWriter or InputStreamReader/InputStreamWriter interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

You have some fundamental problems in your example.

```
class Kitchen:

  ################################
  # Getters/Setters
  ################################

  def get_groceries():
    pass

  ################################
  # Cooking Methods
  ################################

  def cook_chicken():
    pass

  def cook_pasta():
    pass

  ################################
  # Baking Methods
  ################################

  def bake_bread():
    pass

  def bake_cake():
    pass
```

First `Kitchen`s don't get groceries.  Which means your Kitchen is more of a data structure in some aspects than an Object; because, you are exposing groceries to something else, which the kitchen is probably supposed to do.

Second, you are creating compound methods, such that every new item you need to cook or bake will require a new method.  This is bad naming practice because it means the `Kitchen` is not extendable without recompiling the code.

```
    def cook( recipe ):
```

would be a much better design, as it could then take any recipe and cook it.

Finally, baking and cooking are the same kind of transformation, they both convert ingredients into finished edible foods.  As a result of history and techniques, these tend to have different names; but, cooking a loaf of bread is a perfectly valid way of expressing baking a loaf of bread at a high level (just like transporting yourself to the store is a perfectly valid way of saying walking to the store).

So your overall class design probably should be:

```
class Kitchen:

    def add( grocery )

    def use( grocery )

    def cook( recipe )
```

And now the class is both smaller and better designed, extensible and easier to debug, to complete the picture, let's implement recipes for chicken, pasta, bread, and cake:

```
interface Recipe:

   abstract def cook():

class ChickenRecipe implements Recipe:

   def cook(Kitchen kitchen):
       kitchen.use("chicken breast")
       kitchen.use("oil")
       kitchen.use("salt")
       kitchen.use("pepper")
       return "cooked chicken"

class PastaRecipe implements Recipe:

   def cook(Kitchen kitchen):
       kitchen.use("pasta")
       kitchen.use("water")
       kitchen.use("salt")
       kitchen.use("oil")
       return"cooked pasta"

class BreadRecipe implements Recipe:
    
   def cook(Kitchen kitchen):
       kitchen.use("flour")
       kitchen.use("water")
       kitchen.use("salt")
       kitchen.use("yeast")
       return "bread"

class CakeRecipe implments Recipe:

   def cook(Kitchen kitchen):
       kitchen.use("flour")
       kitchen.use("water")
       kitchen.use("salt")
       kitchen.use("sugar")
       kitchen.use("butter")
       return "cake"
```

Now, to evaluate if this approach is useful, let's ask the following questions:

- Can you, upon seeing a Kitchen, and any specific Recipe implement another Recipe?
- How much documentation do you need to read to make a new Recipe?
- Can you add new items to cook, even if the cooking technique doesn't fall into the two categories (cook and bake)?
- Does the interface force you to use it as it is designed? (as opposed to taking all items out of a Kitchen and then putting in a cooked item)

If you have a bunch of related methods, sometimes you don't need a comment to say they are related, you have an interface that you aren't coding like an interface.  For example, you could have easily done a `cook` and a `bake` set of methods, taking parameters.  While that might satisfy the rules of English more nicely, it doesn't actually add functionality, and it is a less effective design because you then have the option of using the wrong interface.

Comment: Thanks. I appreciate the effort. But I'm confident that my code design is not the problem. Bear in mind that this is just an example. My actual code is designed much better than that :)

Comment: @LiranFunaro Then you are a person asking a question, looking for a solution; but finding that all the answers aren't the one you want.  Good luck with that, you just ignored 30 years of software design experience.  I hope you open up to new ideas before you learn everything the hard way.

Comment: You proposed a solution to re-design my example code. That is a nice anecdote, but it is not a solution to the asked question. Bear in mind that it is just an example. In a real system, there are other constraints that may not permit shifting methods to other classes. In addition, these re-designs might have performance implications in cases where the number of objects in the system already overloads the garbage collection.

Comment: Ok, that's a valid assessment; but, the real problem is that you can't put a line in the source code that only applies to lines below that line unless they are in an executable block.  Comments aren't in executable blocks, so it doesn't make sense to have a comment apply to more than the item below it.  So, the solution is to not have "group" comments, but to have the groups collapsed into one item, which removes the need for the group comment (and leads to the design above).  That's why I bothered to redesign it.  The original question can't be answered sufficiently by fixing the comments.